# How to change src source of video in iframe on blogger

Tags: iframe

I have two different sources for a video by uploading the same video onto two different servers

1. `vidstream`
2. `rapidvideo`

I want to stream video in an `iframe` in blogger where the default source is vidstream and there is a option of dropdown in which we can either select vidstream or rapidvideo to stream from the respective source the user selects.

Can you guys help me get the code for this.